# .focus() Jquery one event only being run

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this simple method which gets triggered when i click inside a textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad() {
    $('input:text').focus(function () {
        $('.txt-error-message-icon-email').fadeOut("slow");
        $('input:text').removeClass('txt-error-message');
    });
}
```

Basically the .focus event is supposed to fade out a div and remove a class when i click inside the textbox. This is working however when i click the textbox only the div fades then when i click out of the textbox and click it again the css class is removed. Why are these two events not happening on one .focus event?

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/yfrtu/) this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad() {
    $('input:text').focus(function () {
        $('.txt-error-message-icon-email').fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).removeClass('txt-error-message');
    });
}
```

Try this

Comment: Doubtfully it would change anything. Even though it is correct - the behaviour should stay the same

Comment: but it would reference the current object? isnt it? @zerkms

Comment: yes it would. As I said - your code is more correct, but it would still do the same work. As far as I understand the question - OP is having issue with not removing class at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as your question doesn't share enough details but try this

```
$(this).removeClass('txt-error-message');
```